# Couchbase get the documents within given date range

Tags: java, couchbase

This is the document structure which in my bucket.

```
 {
  "_class": "com.link.pojo.Event",
  "year": "2015",
  "start": 1440115200000,
  "name": "129811",
  "domain": "5000$3$2015$Exhibition",
  "sporttype": "Indoor",
  "eventtype": "Exhibition",
  "end": 1440151199000,
}
```

In here start mean event start date and the type is util Date. Example date format value is `2015-08-10T09:45:00.000+0000`
Now I want to fetch all the documents start in current date using couchbase view. This is the way I'm trying to get it, What are the

```
// Create the CouchbaseClient Query object & Pass the time range to fetch events.
Query query = new Query();
// Filter on the start date and this value has to be within below given range params.
query.setIncludeDocs(true);
query.setDescending(true);
query.setInclusiveEnd(true);
query.setRange(ComplexKey.of(""), ComplexKey.of(""));
List<Event> eventList = `eventService.getEventsByCurrentDate(query);`
```

What are the values I should have to pass within `query.setRange();` function. And what is the view I need to implement?

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if (doc._class == "com.link.pojo.Event") {
    emit(doc.start, null);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I pass two util dates it gives me the `bad_request Reason: invalid UTF-8 JSON: {{error,{1,"lexical error: invalid char in json text.\n"}},` This is the one of example date i passed `Wed Aug 26 16:37:01 PDT 2015`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong :]

A query is just a way to filter some of the results of a view. So start by defining a view - and then work out which query you need to use to get just what you need.

1. start by creating the view in Couchbase UI.
2. then look at the results of the view - again using couchbase UI. There should be a link you can click to see the results of the view in a new tab of your browser.
3. You can then edit the url to "query" the results of your view. add "&key=123 to get just that key. SetRange just means - "get the keys that fall in that range of numbers".
4. in your case, since your view emits the "start" field, your keys (or range) will have to be in the *same* format. So something like &key=1440115200000

I hope this helps.